# Is there a way to delegate the implementation of an interface to a different class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been working on Xamarin for the past couple of years along with Android studio and I decided to create an application for a friend (full source code here https://github.com/nekrull/waiter don't be too harsh please :) )

The idea is that there is a base activity which exchanges fragments when a new screen should appear.

Fragments have everything that has to do with user interaction and the activity they are attached to handles the business logic.

To do this I have a base class `CoreActivity`/`DataActivity` which has some methods most Fragments use (like blocking the back button) and some helper methods (like calling a method on an attached fragment of a specific class) , a `CoreInteraction` that responds to this activity and 
`CoreFragment`/`AttachedFragment` which is used as the base of all view fragments

so for example the view fragment would look like this:

```
public class GroupsFragment extends AttachedFragment<GroupsFragment.GroupsInteraction> {

    //this is what we expect to be able to call in the parent
    public interface GroupsInteraction extends CoreInteraction {
        Group get_shown_group();
        void new_group();
        void select_parent();
    }
}
```

which is basically a fragment that expects its attached activity to be able to respond to the interaction methods.

the activity fragment would look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends DataActivity<MainData> implements
    GroupsFragment.GroupsInteraction, (other interactions here) {
}
```

The problem is that since the application I'm working on has only one Activity with many small screens, the code inside the base activity will get big, that does not cause a problem with the application or compiling or anything else. But it makes it really hard to find what I'm looking for easily.

What I used to do in Xamarin is something like this:

```
public partial class MainActivity : DataActivity<MainData> {
}
```

for the initialization activity and then each interaction would get its own file like this:

```
public partial class MainActivity : GroupsInteraction {
}
```

It had the same effect (since the class is compiled as a single class) but the code would be tidy and easy to read.

Obviously there are no partial classes in Java, but is there a way to delegate the implementation of an interface to another class?

Something along the lines of saying "when you're invoking a method from interface a, invoke it from that class" without actually writing stuff like :

```
public Group get_shown_group() {
    return new GroupHandler(this).get_shown_group();
}
public void new_group() {
    new GroupHandler(this).new_group();
}
public void select_parent() {
    new GroupHandler(this).select_parent();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2):

> Something along the lines of saying "when you're invoking a method from interface a, invoke it from that class"

Taking you literally what you describe is plain *delegation*, a class does not implement some or any functionality itself, instead it *wraps* a class implementing the desired functionality, calling the methods of said *wrapped* class. You could even switch implementation at runtime, just changing the wrapped class as you go (assuming the classes share a common interface, of course). Of course that does not "spare" you from writing the delegations yourself.

```
class Wrapper implements GroupsInteraction {

    private final GroupInteraction gi;        

    public Wrapper(GroupsInteraction gi) {
      this.gi = gi;
    }

    Group get_shown_group() {
       return this.gi.get_shown_group();
    }

    // ... other interface impls
}
```

Additionally, you should keep the GroupHandler as a member instead of creating a new Object each time, so

```
public Group get_shown_group() {
    return new GroupHandler(this).get_shown_group();
}
```

becomes

```
public Group get_shown_group() {
    return this.groupHandler.get_shown_group();
}
```

Comment: For further reference: `you should keep the GroupHandler as a member instead of creating a new Object` : This pattern is often called [Favor Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: That indeed looks much cleaner, I can create new files that way, cause as I wrote in an answer above, right now I'm using static classes to get the responses I need and even though it looks better, it's still a little cluttered, thank you for the information, I will look into the link you gave me and see if that fits my needs

Comment: Don't use static classes here, go for composition. Or else you spread your logic all over the place. Use factories to hide implementation details (like which wrapper delegates to which class) from the caller but keep your logic easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Delegation Pattern**

```
BaseActivity {

  MyDelegateClass delegate;

    void example() {
        delegate.example();
    }
}
```

P.S. both activity and delegate implements same interface

Details [here](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html)

Comment: Yes I've tried somethinglike this, right now, I have one static class for each interaction interface the activity implements and the method (for example `get_shown_groups()` calls a static method from that class (i.e. return `GroupsHandler.GetShownGroups(this)`) it looks MUCH better but it still feels a bit messy